# Gmail on android html (newsletter) is not working as expected

Tags: android, html, css, email, gmail

Hi I am trying to create a html newsletter which is responsive. But I have a weird behavior on mobile especially on gmail android. My tables aren´t expanding fully even if I set them to 100%. Another issue is that the blockquote element gets a border, even if I set them to border: none. Maybe somebody can look over my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <title>Title</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;} 
         body {margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%!important;}
         table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
         img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
         @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic);
         a, .b_link {
         color           : #8e0081;
         text-decoration : none;
         }
         a:hover, a:focus {
         text-decoration : underline;
         }
         p {
         font-family : 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
         font-size   : 16px;
         line-height : 26px;
         }
         h2 {
         font-size   : 24px;
         line-height : 29px;
         font-weight : bold;
         }
         .b_is-small {
         font-size   : 12px;
         line-height : 18px;
         }
         .b_is-bg-purple {
         background : #8e0081;
         }
         .b_is-bg-greenDark {
         background : #5cb431;
         }
         .b_is-bg-greenLight {
         background : #187200;
         }
         .b_is-bg-blue {
         background : #00abba;
         }
         .b_is-bg-gray {
         background : #858b95;
         }
         .b_is-uppercase {
         text-transform : uppercase;
         letter-spacing : .03em;
         }
         .b_is-unstyledLink {
         text-decoration : none;
         color           : inherit;
         }
         .b_logo {
         height : 144px;
         }
         .b_navigation {
         line-height : 30px;
         height      : 30px;
         }
         .b_navigation-link a {
         color      : #fff !important;
         text-align : center;
         display    : block;
         }
         .b_content {
         margin-top : 40px;
         }
         .b_caption {
         font-size   : 10px;
         line-height : 15px;
         color       : #858b95;
         margin      : 0;
         }
         .b_blockquote {
         margin-bottom : 40px;
         padding       : 20px;
         width         : 100%;
         }
         .b_blockquote p {
         color       : #fff;
         font-size   : 18px;
         line-height : 30px;
         }
         .b_blockquote p.c_author {
         font-size   : 14px;
         line-height : 14px;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns .c_meta {
         color  : #858b95;
         margin : 0;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns .c_category {
         color : #858b95;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns-column {
         float         : left;
         width         : 33.3333% !important;
         margin-bottom : 40px;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns-column td {
         padding : 0 6px;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns1-3 td {
         padding-left : 0;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns3-3 td {
         padding-right : 0;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns-column img {
         width  : 100% !important;
         height : auto !important;
         }
         table.b_news-item {
         border-top  : 1px solid #858b95;
         padding-top : 40px;
         margin-top  : 40px;
         }
         table.b_news .c_date {
         color  : #858b95;
         margin : 0;
         }
         table.b_news .c_title {
         margin-bottom : 0;
         }
         table.b_news .c_title + p {
         margin : 0;
         }
         table.b_news .c_date span {
         color : #000;
         }
         table.b_news img {
         float  : left;
         width  : 196px;
         height : 110px;
         }
         table.b_news img + .c_content {
         float       : right;
         width       : 388px;
         margin-left : 12px;
         }
         table.b_footer {
         margin-top     : 40px;
         padding-top    : 40px;
         padding-bottom : 40px;
         color          : #fff;
         }
         table.b_footer .c_title {
         margin-top : 0;
         }
         dl.b_footer-contact dt {
         color       : #858b95;
         width       : 70px;
         float       : left;
         clear       : left;
         overflow    : hidden;
         white-space : nowrap;
         }
         ul.b_social {
         list-style : none;
         margin     : 5px 0 0 0;
         padding    : 0;
         text-align : right;
         display    : inline-block;
         }
         ul.b_social li {
         float       : left;
         display     : inline-block;
         margin-left : 5px;
         }
         ul.b_social li:first-child {
         margin-left : 0;
         }
         table.b_footer .c_footer-social {
         text-align : right;
         width      : 30% !important;
         }
         @media only screen and (max-width : 620px) {
         table.b_navigation .b_container {
            width: 100% !important;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns-column {
         float         : none;
         clear         : both;
         width         : 100% !important;
         margin-bottom : 40px;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns-column td {
         padding : 0;
         }
         table.b_container {
         width : 100% !important;
         }
         table.b_imageteaser img.c_image {
         width  : 100%;
         height : auto;
         }
         table.b_footer .c_footer-address {
         width : 70% !important;
         }
         table.b_imageteaser img.c_image {
         width  : 100%;
         height : auto;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns-column {
         width : 100% !important;
         }
         table.b_threecolumns-column img.c_image{
         width  : 100%;
         height : auto;
         }
         table.b_news img.c_image + .c_content {
         width : 100% !important;
         }
         table.b_news img.c_image {
         width : 100% !important;
         height: auto !important;
         }
         dl.b_footer-contact dt {
         width : 50px;
         }
         table.b_imageteaser img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
         }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="display: table;font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 26px; margin: 0;padding: 0; width: 100%;">
      <table width="100%" style="width: 100% !important;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td valign="top" style="width: 100%;">
                  <table class="b_container" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td valign="top" style="width: 100%;">
                              <p class="b_is-small" style="color: #858b95;font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 12px;line-height: 18px;"><a class="b_link" href="#" style="color: #8e0081;text-decoration: none;"><strong>Online Version</strong></a>.</p>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="b_logo" style="width: 100% !important;background: #282c32;height: 144px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #8e0081;text-decoration: none;"> <img title="Img" alt="Img" src="src.png" height="95" width="211" /><img src="transparent.gif" width="1" height="1" style="width: 100%; height: 1px;" /></a></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="b_navigation" style="width: 100% !important;background: #858b95;line-height: 30px;height: 30px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="width: 100% !important;" valign="top">
                  <table class="b_container" style="width: 100%; width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td valign="top" style="width: 25%;background: #8e0081;" class="b_navigation-link b_is-bg-purple"><a class="b_is-uppercase" href="#" target="_blank" style="text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: .03em;text-align: center;display: block;color: #fff !important;">Link 1</a></td>
                           <td valign="top" style="width: 25%;background: #187200;" class="b_navigation-link b_is-bg-greenLight"><a class="b_is-uppercase" href="#" target="_blank" style="text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: .03em;text-align: center;display: block;color: #fff !important;">Link 2</a></td>
                           <td valign="top" style="width: 25%;background: #5cb431;" class="b_navigation-link b_is-bg-greenDark"><a class="b_is-uppercase" href="#" target="_blank" style="text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: .03em;text-align: center;display: block;color: #fff !important;">Link 3</a></td>
                           <td valign="top" style="width: 25%;background: #00abba;" class="b_navigation-link b_is-bg-blue"><a class="b_is-uppercase" href="#" target="_blank" style="text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: .03em;text-align: center;display: block;color: #fff !important;">Link4</a></td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="b_footer" style="width: 100% !important;background: #282c32;margin-top: 40px;padding-top: 40px;padding-bottom: 40px;color: #fff;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td valign="top">
                  <table class="b_container" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="c_footer-address" style="width: 80%;" valign="top">
                              <h2 class="c_title" style="font-size: 24px;line-height: 29px;font-weight: bold;margin-top: 0;">Name</h2>
                              <p style="font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;">Lorem <br />Ipsum<br />Dolor</p>
                              <dl class="b_footer-contact">
                                 <dt style="color: #858b95;width: 70px;float: left;clear: left;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;">Fax</dt>
                                 <dd>(3333) 378 78</dd>
                                 <dt style="color: #858b95;width: 70px;float: left;clear: left;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;">E-Mail</dt>
                                 <dd><a class="b_is-unstyledLink" style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:lorem@ipsum.de">lorem@ipsum.de</a></dd>
                              </dl>
                              Unsubscribe <a class="b_link" href="#" style="color: #8e0081;text-decoration : none;color: #8e0081;text-decoration: none;"><strong>here</strong></a> 
                           </td>
                           <td class="c_footer-social" style="width: 20%;text-align: right;" valign="top">
                              <ul class="b_social" style="list-style: none;margin: 5px 0 0 0;padding: 0;text-align: right;display: inline-block;">
                                 <li style="float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 0;"><a class="b_link" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #8e0081;text-decoration: none;"><img src="facebook.png" title="Name" alt="Name" height="18" width="18" /></a></li>
                                 <li style="float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 5px;"><a class="b_link" href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #8e0081;text-decoration: none;"><img src="twitter.png" title="Name" alt="Name" height="18" width="18" /></a></li>
                                 <li style="float: left;display: inline-block;margin-left: 5px;"><a class="b_link" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #8e0081;text-decoration: none;"><img src="youtube.png" title="Name" alt="Name" height="18" width="22" /></a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <img src="stat.gif" border="0" alt="" height="1" width="1">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is body defined twice? Remove it from first place and define it by only stating what's different.

Comment: Try reducing provided code. unless one is paid, it's unreal to go through all that.

Comment: Ok thank you for the hint. I reduced the code to my header and footer, which is the real problem. I tried several things to expand it to full with on my android device (b_navigation and b_footer).

Comment: I'll take a look. Hope I remember, but unfortunately there is no option to mark a notification unread.